# Is that a good solution to handle multi language website?

Tags: .net, web-applications, web

I already have a solution for multi language website, but I'm not sure whether is that a good solution.. and as much flexible as it could be. 
First of, I'm developing a project using Visual webgui. Long story short, webgui is a web programming but very similar to WinForms.

So, Here it is:

1. I've got an MDI application. It is a simple webpage with MainMenu on the top and ability to open many windows inside.
2. First of all I create resx file in my main startup project. Let's say `"myStrings.resx"` for default language and `"myStrings.de-DE.resx`" for german translation.
3. Every string which will be translated has to be in that two resources files.
4. Now, my biggest concern. In every class (Form or no-Form) I must have method like this (in this example there is only one control to translate):

   ```
   private void adjustCulture()
       {
           System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyApp.myStrings", typeof(testWindow).Assembly);
           label2.Text = rm.GetString("DefaultString", culture);
       }
   ```

And this bother me a lot, because I have to implement this function in every window separately. And not exactly for every control in that window (only that ones, which will be translated). So It is a little bit "not-flexible".

5.I also, cannot just initialize label in my designer, I have to do all initialization in constructor manually:

```
label2.Text = rm.GetString("DefaultString", culture);

(or in Designer partial class inside InitializeComponent method - but also, manually).
```

6.And finally, When Somebody changes language:

I have to call adjustCulture function in Load event in EVERY window, always! First of all, to initialize.. and secondly, when somebody (in MDI menu) changes Language to German and I have opened three windows in my MDI at that moment.. I have to translate everyone separately. So I have to store somewhere opened windows handlers, and call Load event of everyone.

Is that a good solution for multilanguage webgui appliacation ? Or is there any better solution? more flexible ?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to have a xml file per each language with Key/Value pairs and use it as your translator for different languages. In this case, you can also implement the caching, rtl/ltr and other necessary attributes you want for each expression. You can have write a library for it and then you can easily add support for different languages and also automate the translation and other features.

Comment: Why have one xml file per language when you can structure the file so that each text-node has another node for each language. Saves you the work to go through multiple files to change a translation.

Comment: Well, I wrote about xml. Format .resx consists of XML entries.
I will have resx file per language. I will switch between them like in 4.

Comment: @boldty in case that you want to only load one language texts and cache it for future usages. It can be done in only one file depending on the scale of the website. In my scenario, we had more than 32 projects each had its own dictionary

Comment: @Marshall I suggest to store the default language in each user's Session object and have a class in your library layer to handle the text translation for you. This class can have a method like GetString(string key, HttpSessionState session) to read the default language from it and return the related string to your UI layer

Comment: So, when I open new window (new Form in VisalWebGui project), in constructor I have to initlialize every control, that will be translated latter, by method GetString(string key, HttpSessionState session), right? And when somebody switches to German, first I change Context (so Session object in VWG) and then need to reinitialize every control (which will be translated) again, right?

Comment: You don't need to reinitialize every control as long as you get all you texts from GetString method. The only thing you need to do when a user changes his language, you update the user's language in his session and then you don't need to do anything else. As Session object is per user, the GetString method for each user will return the text in the user's preferred language.